# Count the number of times the same label was consecutively predicted by the model

Tags: python

```
cap = VideoStream().start()
while True:
            frame=cap.read()
            Detect = detection_method(frame)
            if detect:
                Predict_label=function(recognize)
            (Step 4)#Do somthing on this predict_label

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()   
Label is for example:unknown,cat,dog,panda,...
```

In the piece of code shown above, I capture the frame of the camera and identify the objects using a method of detection, and I have a predict on these objects, and when these objects are identified, for example, the corresponding image of those objects I show.
My preblem is that if for the first time the label is "dog", Then the system again tries to identify the object and predict label, and if the second time is detected ‘dog’ Let’s continue to run step 4  Otherwise, step 4 will not be executed.how i do it?
My ultimate goal is to reduce the sensitivity of the model.
What comes to my mind is to count the number of times the model twice predicts a label, but I can not implement it.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a stateful system, so you have to store the previous states to be able to decide what to do everytime you detect something.

You can use for example a `collections.deque` to achieve that, see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
cap = VideoStream().start()
previous_detections = collections.dequeue(maxlen=5) # adapt for your own purposes
while True:
        frame = cap.read()
        detection = detection_method(frame)
        previous_detections.append(detection) # store the detection
        if detection:
            # use all previous states for your own logic
            # I am not familiar with opencv so this will likely not work, consider it pseudo-code
            # this is supposed to check if all previous known detections are the same as the current one
            if all(previous_detection == detection for previous_detection in previous_detections):
                predict_label = function(recognize)
                (Step 4)#Do somthing on this predict_label

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much,What if I want to repeat steps if only a specific label is predicted?
For example, if only my label is 'unknown', then repeat detection, otherwise, after detecting each label except "unknown", step 4 will be executed.

Comment: just add some conditional tests (`if` statements) to branch a "unkown" detection out of your step4. I don't know `opencv` so I can't help you much in that area

Comment: Ohhh sorry,detection is not label,i want to save label .detection is only object detection

Comment: When each object is facing the camera, detection is performed, and then the model acts to determine what this object is and then decides what to label.